# Manage web.config in sitecore multisite solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

We have a multisite solution with individual visual studio solutions for each websites. Then we have master solution to build/deploy all websites.

Firstly, not sure whether it's a best practice to include web.config in Visual Studio solution. But I think all the nuget packages needs web.config to add their settings.

As a result, we have web.config for each solution. However when we deploy from master web.config gets overwritten by each sites.

Could someone please suggest how this issue can be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise for each website (under its individual project) to create it's own **App_Config/Include** folder and create **_project_name_.config** within that folder in order to keep all site-specific settings there (for further merge into resulting config).

On build you set up (for each individual project) that file to be copied into main **SITECORE_INSTANCE_WEB_ROOT\App_config\Include** folder along with the rest of include patch config files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin, we can do that for app setting and sitecore specific settings. What if we have added new configSections etc. other example is update of session state from InProc to Custom etc. Is above possible via app_config\include?

Comment: I am 100% sure you can do that for ANYTHING what sits under <sitecore> node in config file! Haven't tested with externals like httpHandlers and similar, do not think they would work for sitecore's config patching. ALSO: not related to the question but I would advise to extract whole <sitecore> section out of web.config into individual config file App_Config\Sitecore.config

Comment: Thanks Martin. On other post you've implemented multi-solution for your projects. How did you manage the changes that requires sitecore updates e.g. WCF settings, Azure Service bus settings that may require for site when consuming end points.

Comment: I do not have neither WCF, nor Azure. The rest of them like <sessionState>  are shared across the whole instance.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is 
Use the APP_Config\Include directory, or better yet create for each project its own directory under the include folder. try to change the web.config minimal as possible. (then you can excluding the web.config from you deploy)

The nuget packages with changes for the web.config outside the `<sitecore>` tag. can not set inside the include folder, needs manually managed.

Comment: So we need to manually update the web.config file for each environment everytime we we add new nuget packeges?

Comment: It does not happen very often that there are changes in the web.config. outside the sitecore tag,  If that happens a lot then you need to manage that somehow. what kind of nugets are you using? (
perhaps one joint web.config, as the changes do not broke other projects without the package?)

Answer (score 0):

I would leave one web.config in the main site and remove web.config files from other web-projects. The reason is that you can't have different web.config files per multisite anyway.

As per the site-specific settings as noted above they should be stored in App_Config files.